# Fuzzing command line arguments [argv]

Tags: reverse-engineering, argv, exploit, fuzzing, american-fuzzy-lop

I have a binary I've been trying to fuzz with AFL, the only thing is AFL only fuzzes STDIN, and File inputs and this binary takes input through its arguments `pass_read [input1] [input2]`. I was wondering if there are any methods/fuzzers that allow fuzzing in this manner?

I don't not have the source code so making a harness is not really applicable.

Comment: What type of inputs does it accept as args?

Comment: So you are looking for a tool like `xargs`? Or just patching AFL yourself?

Comment: @DSilveiro it accepts just two strings

Comment: @Ext3h I'm looking for a method to fuzz the positional arguments of this binary, I was hopefully looking for another tool but if patching AFL is the only way to accomplish this I may have too

Answer (score 4):

Michal Zalewski, the creator of AFL, states in this [post](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/afl-users/ZBWq0LdHBzw/zBlo7q9LBAAJ):

> AFL doesn't support argv fuzzing, because TBH, it's just not horribly useful in
> practice. There is an example in experimental/argv_fuzzing/ showing how to do it
> in a general case if you really want to.

Link to the mentioned example on GitHub: https://github.com/google/AFL/tree/master/experimental/argv_fuzzing

There are some instructions in the file [argv-fuzz-inl.h](https://github.com/google/AFL/blob/master/experimental/argv_fuzzing/argv-fuzz-inl.h) (haven't tried myself).

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I saw this example before and unfortunately it only works if you have the source code available, the binary I am trying to fuzz is black box.

Comment: @rooter Just out of interest ... did you try the above `xargs` suggestion from @Ext3h?

Answer (score 1):

I looked at the `AFLplusplus` repo on GitHub. Inside `AFLplusplus/utils/argv_fuzzing/`, there is a `Makefile`. If you run it, you will get a `.so` file (a shared library) that you can use to do `argv` fuzzing, even if you only have the binary. Obviously, you must use `AFL_PRELOAD`. You can read more in the `README`.

Comment: I checked out this solution before, unfortunately it seems you still need to patch the source to call AFL_INIT_ARGV() macro in order for this method to work.

Answer (score 0):

**Bash only Solution**

As an example, lets generate 10 random strings and store them in a file

```
cat /dev/urandom | tr -dc 'a-zA-Z0-9' | fold -w 10 | head -n 10 > string-file.txt
```

Next, lets read 2 lines from string-file and pass it into our application

```
exec handle< string-file.txt

while read string1 <&handle ; do
        read string2 <&handle

        pass_read $line1 $line2 >> crash_file.txt
done

exec handle<&-
```

We then have any crashes stored within `crash_file.txt` for further analysis.

This may not be the most elegant solution, but perhaps you gives you an idea of some other possibilities if no tool necessarily fulfills the current requirements

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I looked at zuff and I don't believe it solves my issue since it also only takes a filename as fuzzing inputs. AFL actually does have a QEMU mode for non-instrumented binaries without the source but my issue is I have no method of fuzzing since it doesn't allow fuzzing argument strings for the binary